# Keyboard with hardware macros?

Tags: keyboard, macros

Are there any keyboards with extra programmable keys for which there is hardward-only support for macros? In other words, the macros can be programmed and played back on any OS without installing any software. Preferably one that would save the macros to flash memory inside the keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

SkyDigital Inc,(www.SkyOK.co.kr), Model name: 'nKEYBOARD Mechanic2' has 6 keys in hardware  macro. They ad it's a first product in the world.

Answer (score 3):

There’s a [new piece of hardware](http://emukey.com/) getting [crowd-funded](http://www.indiegogo.com/emukey/) that looks to do what you’re asking for. Their tagline is *The functionality of macro software in a hardware device*. Think of a hardware version of AutoIt, but undetectable as it appears to Windows as an input device like a keyboard or mouse! It records and plays back keystrokes and mouse clicks and movements.

I think this is a huge evolution from macro software to macro hardware. I really want to get one of these (I have already contributed to the project) so I’m spreading the word so that they meet their goal and manufacture them. If you are at all interested in this, buy one and tell your friends!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tech-critter.com/2013/04/unboxing-review-armaggeddon-taranis-kai.html

damn i must find one with swedish layout. i guess i could settle for one of the lesser ones.

Answer (score 0):

The Corsair line has a number of mice and keyboards with onboard storage for hardware macros, although you need their software to configure them.

http://www.corsair.com/en-eu/blog/2013/november/setting-a-macro

> **Hardware Playback**
>
> Some games may prevent the software from being utilized since it may
>   present an unfair advantage. However, there is a way to bypass this by
>   utilizing the profile directly from the hardware itself.
>
> To save the profile to the peripheral, all you have to do is click on
>   the button that says "Save to K90/K95/M40/60/M65" for those devices.
>   Then you would check the box "Hardware Playback" so the software will
>   no longer be needed.
>
> [...]
>
> There will be some limitations to Hardware Playback due to how it
>   interfaces with the OS. Anything you have binded that launches
>   applications or does an OS command will not work, for example, due to
>   the OS not allowing an external component to execute it. However,
>   macros and key stroke bindings will continue to work so you can use
>   them for the games you enjoy.